# How do I integrate dataflow in a pipeline with the source as a dataset to perform transformation on each table seperately?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to retrieve multiple tables from a database, add a derived column in each one of them, and save it into the same database.

I tried using a copy table and data flow in the pipeline, but I was not able to insert a dynamic value in the source data set of the data flow. So that it can take a single file at a time from the database, perform the transformation, and store it in the sink.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataset for each of your source tables.
then create a Data Flow activity for each table you want to process.
Use a Sink transformation to write the data to the destination.

Create a dataset for each of your destination tables.
Pipeline. Create a pipeline and add a Data Flow activity for each table.
Iterating Through Tables:

Use the debug mode in ADF to test your pipeline and data flows individually.
ill give a sample snippet here

```html
"source": {
    "type": "AzureSqlTable",
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "YourLinkedServiceName",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "typeProperties": {
        "tableName": {
            "value": "@pipeline().parameters.TableName",
            "type": "Expression"
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest you to visit this link and follow the documentation for detailed info on how to create etc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=azure%20data%20factory

Answer (score 0):

For this, you should have the table names list which you want to transform. Pass that table names array to For Each activity. To use dataflow for the multiple tables, you need to use dataset parameters for the table name of the dataset like below.

First create a string parameter for the table name.

[image]

Give this parameter `@dataset().table_name` as dynamic content for the table name in the dataset.

[image]

As your source and sink in the dataflow are in same database, give this dataset as source and as sink of the dataflow. Check on **Recreate table** option in the sink settings of the dataflow for the new table creation.

[image]

Inside ForEach, take dataflow activity and pass the current table name `@item()` to these parameters.

[image]

Here, I am creating new table `<current_table_name>_target` in the same database for every source table by using the expression like `@concat(item(),'_target')`.

If you pass the same table names in each iteration, dataflow will add the new column, but it won't copy the rows data from the original table. So, that's why I am creating new tables for every source table. If you want, you can drop the original table by using `drop` command in the dataflow sink post SQL script.

Now, execute the pipeline and new column will be added for every table like below.

**Source tables:**

[image]

**Target tables after pipeline execution:**

[image]